# Access control lists and permission on directory or folder

Tags: linux, ubuntu, setfacl

I have user bala-sftp. Evertime the user writes a file to folder /balab/settlement/report
currently it is

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 bala-sftp        sftponly  5295 Oct 18 19:00 settlementreport_switch_20201018.csv
```

but permission should be

```
-rw-r----- 1 bala-sftp        sftponly  5295 Oct 18 19:00 settlementreport_switch_20201018.csv
```

How can I acheive this via setfacl ?

Answer (score 0):

This will ensure new files created in `/balab/settlement/report` are group readable, but not group writable.

```
setfacl -m -d g::r /balb/settlement/report
```

Here is an example if it in action:

```
stew ~$ umask 0002                               # New files will be -rw-rw-r-- like yours
stew ~$ cd $(mktemp -d)                          # Going to a new directory
stew /tmp/tmp.JgZyxzKcf8 $ getfacl .             # It has no ACL rules yet
# file: .
# owner: stew
# group: stew
user::rwx
group::---
other::---

stew /tmp/tmp.JgZyxzKcf8 $ touch before          # File to demonstrate pre-ACL rule
stew /tmp/tmp.JgZyxzKcf8 $ setfacl -d -m g::r .  # Set the default acls to group-read-only
stew /tmp/tmp.JgZyxzKcf8 $ touch after           # File to demonstrate post-ACL rule
stew /tmp/tmp.JgZyxzKcf8 $ ls -lr
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 stew stew 0 Nov  2 12:39 before     # Pre-ACL is world readable 
-rw-r----- 1 stew stew 0 Nov  2 12:39 after      # Post-ACL is group readable only
```

New files that are group-writable is a little weird.  If `bala-sftp`'s `umask` outputs `0022` (linux default), then you may need to delete existing ACLs.  Do that with `setfacl -b /balb/settlement/report`. I suspect `bala-sftp`'s `umask` is `0002` which is why I set my own `umask` like that during my test.